# Could a spinning permanent magnet's interaction with the Earth's magnetic field propel a boat through the water?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, applied-mechanics, experimental-physics

I am wondering if a spinning permanent magnet's interaction with the Earth's magnetic field will produce a propelling force strong enough to propel a toy boat through the water. This propelling force would be most effective when the toy boat travels due North and stays on that course.

Please reference the drawing below. A permanent magnet would be fastened to a non-metallic bar that is perpendicular to an electric motor's shaft and on the other end of this bar would be a non-metallic counterweight. Say that the toy boat is 1 foot long, the magnet is a .5 inch cube N52 Neodymium magnet, the motor is spinning at 3000 rpm, and boat is in an indoor swimming pool.

The basic concept is that as the magnet is rotated from the position of facing due North to facing due South (180 degree rotation), the motor will have to push the magnet through the Earth's magnetic field and the reaction to this is that the toy boat will be pushed through the water. As the magnet is rotated from the position of facing due South to facing due North (180 degree rotation), the motor will not have to push the magnet through the Earth's magnetic field. So, during each full/360 degree rotation of the motor's shaft, the magnet's interaction with the Earth's magnetic field should create a paddle wheel effect that should propel the toy boat forward.

Could this magnetic paddle wheel effect propel this boat through the water?

Also, I am wondering if the rotational speed of the motor has a direct effect on the amount of propelling force that is generated. For example, will the motor have a harder time pushing the magnet through the Earth's magnetic field when it is spinning at 3000 rpm as compared to spinning at only 500 rpm?

EDIT

I had to insert a revised drawing because the original drawing had the magnet positioned in the wrong orientation. Also added text to help convey concept.

[image]

Comment: Won’t the force be opposite when the magnet is at the top?

Comment: @Solar Mike, well the way I see it is that the Earth's magnetic field will be pulling the magnet towards the magnetic South pole when it is at the top and the same thing will occur when the magnet is at the bottom. The overall effect should be that the boat is pulled/pushed towards the magnetic South pole of the Earth.

Comment: You're dangerously close to expecting perpetual motion. The magnet interacts with the Earth's field in **all** orientations, not just at "top and bottom."  There is no way you can extract more energy from the field than you have to put back in.

Comment: Why wouldnt  every electric motor then get  a push from earth?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, I think there may be some confusion over how things are depicted in my drawing and I think I may need to redraw it to make the concept more clear. The picture above is showing a side view of the boat and it is moving in a northward direction indicated by the compass North symbol located at the top of the drawing. I believe that people may be thinking that the boat is moving towards the North symbol located at the top of the page. When the motor is turned off, the Earth's magnetic field will pull on the magnet until it is pointing due North, just like a compass needle.

Comment: @joojaa, that's a good question, I'm not sure if they do or not.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, I just revised the drawing and reinserted it. I hope this removes any confusion that may have been caused by my original drawing.

Comment: So how does your edit help?

Comment: @Solar Mike, I just wanted to make it more clear that the drawing is a side view of the boat and not a rear/stern view of the boat.

Comment: The earths magnetic field is used to apply a torque to some satellites:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer

Comment: @Adam, thanks for the link. That is a technology that I didn't know existed. Very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like anyone who has used a compass knows, earth's magnetic field does exert a force on magnetic objects.  In theory this force could be harnessed to do work, but in practice it is too small to be a concern.

For example, a 1 meter long wire carrying 1 amp of current sitting perpendicular to earth's magnetic field will be subject to about 0.0001 Newtons of force.  That's not going to be enough to overcome friction let alone build up any noticeable amount of speed.  For comparison, dropping a paper clip off the side of a table exerts 100 times that force.

As to your "paddle wheel":  The magnet is always in earth's field and is the equivalent of a paddle wheel that is fully submerged in the water.  That means the force exerted on your spinning magnet will follow a typical sinusoid pattern, resulting in net zero work.  You would be better off just leaving the magnet stationary, but don't expect your boat to move a noticeable distance unless you see all the iron objects in the world flying towards the poles.

Comment: well not quite, the magnet has no charge since the permanent magnet has both positive and negative charge so while it can easily orient itself it can not be used to generate power. The magnet needs to be in,a area where the field is starting to change abruptly so that the ends dont experience same force.

Comment: Not power, force, sorry.

Comment: @joojaa to nitpick, any field strength change will work, albeit moving the magnet slower than the famous pitchblende drop experiment :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft but offcourse, just that the magnetic field on earth is locally constant. It is better to make the shaft even slightly slanted and use it as propeller. ;)